# How to display category id at database and at frontend display category name with an array?

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, categories, gradle-custom-plugin

I am currently working on another custom plugin of Wordpress named as game-plugin.

I have fields like Id,Name,Category,Image,Popularity,Company,Content.

I am trying to insert category id at my database table game_db and I want to fetch my selected multiple categories to frontend.

I used Implode function to store category id to database table that is working fine.

```
//implode : Join array elements with a string
 'category' => implode(', ', $category)
```

I need to display selected categories name to frontend.